# Register user in an Angular/Symfony application

Tags: angular, symfony, api-platform.com

I am wondering what is the recommanded way to register a new user in an application using angular as a frontend and symfony (with api-platform) as a back-end.

Currently I just post a new user object to api/users. However I feel like this would not be a best practice, as I need to expose this route for anonymously  authenticated users.

I would prefer to use a signup route, exposed to anonymously authenticated users, and expose the api/users route only for fully authenticated users with a role such as ROLE_ADMIN.

So my questions are :

- Am I overthinking this ?
- If not, how to implement this on the symfony side ?

For now I have a SignUpController like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/signup", name="signup")
 */
public function signUpAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        try {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            return new JsonResponse($user);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new JsonResponse($e->getMessage(), 500);
        }
    }
}
```

But this way the methodes like `$form->isSubmitted()` and `$form->isValid()` are not available, and more importantly the `$form->handleRequest()` does nothing, meaning I would have to hydrate my `$user` object manually, which is far from ideal.

Comment: There should be something like `http interceptors` in symfony. This may be useful - https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html

Answer (score 1):

> Your scenario could be achieved using Angular too! So, please consider this only if you want to do it using Angular!

You could efficiently use angular *'Route Guards'* for this purpose.
The following code demonstrates the use of route guards -

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const currentUser = this.userService.getCurrentUser();
    this.currentUserRole = currentUser ? JSON.parse(currentUser)['role'] : undefined;
    this.currentUserRole = this.currentUserRole ? this.currentUserRole.toLowerCase() : undefined;
    const isLoggedIn = this.userService.isLoggedIn();
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (this.currentUserRole == 'admin') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

And, in your routes -

```
{ path: 'api/users', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},    // AuthGuard is the name of Guard Class
{ path: 'signup', component: PublicComponent }
```

Refer **[this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/route_guards.html)** for more details.

Comment: That's interesting but I don't think this is what I am looking for. I would still need to post the new user to the api using a route opened to everyone (using cUrl for example), and that's what bothers me. Thanks anyway :)